# Excel VBA: VLookup on array from range as Variant throws "Type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Following Problem:
I am running VLookups on big data (using [double-true VLookup](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/)), thus I would like to load the data into an array first.

VLookup statement:

```
Application.VLookup(vLookUpKey, vLookUpRange, 1, True)
```

The following piece of code loads a range into the memory as array:

```
Dim vLookUpRange As Variant
vLookUpRange = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(2, 1), dataSheet.Cells(30000, 10)).Value
```

When defining the above lookup-range as Range it looks like this:

```
Dim vLookUpRange As Range
Set vLookUpRange = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(2, 1), dataSheet.Cells(30000, 10))
```

When it is defined as range the below VLookup runs without a problem (but slow, since I access the sheet all the time). If I use the version where it is loaded into an array as Variant it Throws a "Type mismatch" error.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: We might benefit from seeing more of your code.

Comment: You also may benefit *a lot* in terms of performance by ditching the double vlookup embedded into an IF statement and using `Index(Match)` instead. It's a lot faster and more efficient overall. And I am pretty sure the `Variant` array does not work for the *specific* error reason you get. the `vlookup` formula expects an `Excel Range Object` as the 2nd argument, and you are not giving it that.

Comment: The most likely reason for a type mismatch is that your lookup value isn't found. But your premise is flawed, it is likely that using the range will be faster than using the array version especially if you use `Worksheetfunction.Vlookup`

Comment: @MattCremeens: Sure that would help, but the code is rather complex, I cannot just copy that here. I will try to create a small example and post that.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: The problem is the amount of lookups. Index match is not as fast as the double-true VLookup (but surley faster than the "usual" VLookup). My knowledge comes from this post: [EXCEL: VLOOKUP vs INDEX MATCH vs SQL vs VBA](http://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/). I actually implemented the problem with Index(Match) and this accepts an array - I was wondering why VLookup would not, when Index(Match) does. [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx) states that the type has to be a "Table_Array"

Comment: @Rory: I know that the values are found, because when I just use the range (without loading it to memory) the code works. I don't think my premise is flawed - by loading code to memory one can speed-up the performance according to the [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673%28v=office.14%29.aspx#xlFasterVBA). If I got this wrong please explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Note: I gave up on this problem for the moment (gave up on double-true VLookup version) and implemented the problem using dictionaries (load ranges into arrays and then fill the lookup data into dictionary from in-memory array, then lookup the keys (which are also loaded into in-memory array) in the dictionary). The problem mentioned above was not solved, but for the moment the dictionary version is performant enough as solution, so the problem above is not relevant any more ;)